# Python 3 formatting issue with '$'

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I just started learning Python this week and I'm having an issue with some line formatting. I am trying to insert a '$' along with the calculated values, I've tried to insert the '$' with a new {} set, as well as here `{{$:>{}.2f}}` (based on Google search suggestions), however I keep getting errors.

I'm using Google Collab to run the code.

```html
def budget_calc(money, rent, food, phone, gas, extra_income):
  width = 35
  price_width = 10
  item_width = width - price_width
  income = sum(weekly_income) + extra_income
  expenses = sum(credit_cards) + rent + phone + food + gas + utilities

  after_tax =income*0.84
  #after_tax_instr = str(after_tax)

  gross = 'Money before tax:'           #+ str(income)

  post_tax= 'Post tax income:'          #+after_tax_instr

  tax_payment ='Taxes due:'             #+str(income*.16) 

  savings = after_tax - expenses

  total = 'Money left over:'            #+'$'+str(savings)

  expense_total = 'Total expenses'      #+str([expenses])

  line = "{{:{}}} {{:>{}.2f}}".format(item_width,  price_width)
  
  print(line.format(gross, income))
  print(line.format(tax_payment, (income*0.16)))
  print(line.format(post_tax, after_tax))
  print(line.format(expense_total, expenses))
  print(line.format(total, savings))
```

The output I get is:

```
Money before tax:            3300.00
Taxes due:                    528.00
Post tax income:             2772.00
Total expenses               2190.00
Money left over:              582.00
Days until my Mac:             44.36
```

I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: What errors do you get ? What is your desired output

Answer (score 1):

I think the error it throws will be `keyerror` and it because of the messy string format

```
def budget_calc(money, rent, food, phone, gas, extra_income):
  width = 35
  price_width = 10
  item_width = width - price_width
  income = sum(weekly_income) + extra_income
  expenses = sum(credit_cards) + rent + phone + food + gas + utilities

  after_tax =income*0.84
  #after_tax_instr = str(after_tax)

  gross = 'Money before tax:'           #+ str(income)

  post_tax= 'Post tax income:'          #+after_tax_instr

  tax_payment ='Taxes due:'             #+str(income*.16) 

  savings = after_tax - expenses

  total = 'Money left over:'            #+'$'+str(savings)

  expense_total = 'Total expenses'      #+str([expenses])


  # You can specify the width integer instead of formating 
  line = "{0:<25} ${1:.2f}"
  
  print(line.format(gross, income))
  print(line.format(tax_payment, (income*0.16)))
  print(line.format(post_tax, after_tax))
  print(line.format(expense_total, expenses))
  print(line.format(total, savings))
```

> Note : since weekly_income and credit_cards are not provided i just
> removed it from script in order to check the output

When `budget_calc(33000,500,10,100,152,510)` this is called the output

Output :

```
Money before tax:          $33510.00
Taxes due:                 $5361.60
Post tax income:           $28148.40
Total expenses             $762.00
Money left over:           $27386.40
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6+ String interpolation is recommended way of string formatting because of its high readabililty.

The best way would be:

`print(f'Money before tax: {income}')`

`print(f'Taxes due:{income*0.16}')`

`print(f'Post tax income: {after_tax}')`

`print(f'Total expenses: {expenses}')`

`print(f'Money left over :{savings}')`

But if you want to use `$` String Formatting only , the you should try the answer by [DaVinci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62588615/12982627)

Comment: You can also get rid of the unnecessary memory storage for the strings